# How to get the Terms and conditions content in phtml?

Tags: magento2, phtml, terms-and-conditions

I need help, please.

- I created a cms page with `id=terms`
- I insert in the content of web page this code:

  ```
  {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::test/test.phtml"}}
  ```
- I create the `test.phtml` file in folder:

  public_html/app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/test
- Into `test.phtml` I insert the code:

  ```
  <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>;
  ```

All it's alright. The output of `www.dominio.com/terms` is "hello world".

Now I would like changing the php code for display the Terms and Conditions configured in `STORE`, `SETTINGS`.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this store settings ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to get in your phtml the content of your `termes & conditions` set in `Stores > under Settings > Terms and Conditions.`

So **1st solution** and the best is to add some function in your block module then you get that function in your phtml to avoid using directly the objectManager in a phtml, **2nd solution** you can do it direclty in phtml without a block but it is not recommended.

**1st solution:**

**app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Block/agreements.php**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Block;
class agreements extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_agreements;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement $agreements
    )
    {
        $this->_agreements = $agreements;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getAgreements($agreementId)
    {
        $agree =  $this->_agreements->load($agreementId);
        return $agree->getContent();
    }
}
```

in `test.phtml` you add this :

```
<?php echo $this->getAgreements(1); ?> //1 is the termes & conditions ID
```

**2nd solution**

**test.phtml**

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();?>
<?php $agreements = $objectManager->create('Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Agreement')->load(1);?> //here 1 is the ID of your termes & conditions.
<?php echo $agreements->getContent();?>
```

Comment: hi @Prince, can you please explain in detail? can we show terms and condtions from cms block in checkout?

Comment: @PЯINCƎ how to get Terms and Conditions id dynamically?